# Visualforce rerender encoding { and } in firefox

Tags: apex, visualforce, browser

When trying to rerender a pageBlockSection with an image tag inside to pick up a new src url from the controller, chrome works just fine but Firefox is encoding the { and the }. Is there any way to stop Firefox from doing that?

NOTE: The brackets are in the url for the image. Yes, this is not normal but it is how Scene7 is set up.

NOTE 2: Oh shoot, I didn't proofread and put escape when I meant encode. The brackets are getting encoded for urls, scenes 7 is choking on that.

Comment: I cannot give an actual or example url because of the nature of what I am working on but here is the desired format BASE_URL/PATH?PILE_OF_PARAMETERS{MORE_PATH?A_FEW_MORE_PARAMETERS}&ONE_LAST_PARAMETER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I needed the unencoded values in the url and salesforce was (rightfully) encoding it, I used javascript to change the url and replace the encoded brackets with the brackets themselves.

Answer (score 3):

You have to **encode** your url.

- { ==> `%7B`
- } ==> `%7D`

Sample :

- url decoded: http://site.com?paramerer={value}
- url params encoded: http://site.com?paramerer=%7Bvalue%7D

Try manually using this: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Also, you could use this function: `{!URLENCODE('{value}')}`

Comment: I added another edit. Scene 7 has an issue with %7B & %7D.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get what are you trying to do. Could you add a sample url or code that what are you printing and what is expecting?

Comment: I put the sort of layout I expect in the comments for my post